# I need to calculate percentage of counted items

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datatable

I have two tables:

1st: reasons

```
id   |   title   
---------------------------------  
1    |   Customer didn't like it  
2    |   Needs improving         
3    |   Wrong format
```

2nd: projects

```
id   |   title       |   rejected
------------------------------------  
1    |   Priject 1   |   Null
2    |   Priject 2   |   1  
3    |   Priject 3   |   1  
4    |   Priject 4   |   Null  
5    |   Priject 5   |   2
```

I need to display Reasons.Title and number of project rejected for that reason. I've managed to join those tables together, with this code

```
SELECT reasons.title as title, count(*) as num
FROM reasons
LEFT JOIN reasons on projects.rejected = reasons.id
WHERE projects.rejectedIS NOT NULL
GROUP BY projects.rejected
```

Now I need to add percentage, so my final table looks like this

```
title                    |   num   |  percentage 
--------------------------------------------------  
Customer didn't like it  |   2     |  66,6
Needs improving          |   1     |  33,3
```

The format of percentage is of course not important.
I would like to get this done with MySql, so I do not need to use two queries and extra PHP, **but if there is another solution**, other from MySql, I'm open to suggestions

Comment: You're not joining with the `projects` table. Did you mean `left join projects`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by getting the total in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT r.title as title, count(*) as num,
       COUNT(*) / pp.cnt as ratio
FROM reasons r JOIN 
     projects p
     ON p.rejected = r.id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM projects p WHERE rejects IS NOT NULL) pp
GROUP BY r.title, pp.cnt;
```

Notes:

- This fixes the table names, so the query has a `projects` table.
- This removes the `WHERE` because it is not needed.
- This changes the `LEFT JOIN` to an inner join.

Comment: Need to change `count(*)` to `count(projects.id)`, otherwise you'll count 1 row even when there's no match.